# Plot graph for either loss or accuracy of the keras predictive model

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, graph, keras

So I am trying to plot a graph for my model, say I have 20 epochs and the graph should show the accuracy/loss on each epoch. As of now I found this code on Keras website.

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 128,validation_split = 0.2)
plot(history)
```

I tried using this on my data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history)
```

So this is the error I am getting

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'History'
```

Is there any way of correcting this or any other way of plotting a graph for each  epoch?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you show a sample R code instead of the Python code that produces your error? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```
model_history = model.fit(...

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(model_history.history['accuracy'])
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(model_history.history['loss'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's often better to add some explanation to your code. What have you done/changed that solved the problem? See [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
print(history.history.keys()) # Displays keys from history, in my case loss,acc
plt.plot(history.history['acc']) #here I am trying to plot only accuracy, the same can be used for loss as well
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()
```